# Weird nullable comparison behavior

Tags: c#, linq, nullable, comparator

What is the rational (if any) behind the following behavior:

```
int? a = null;
Console.WriteLine(1 > a); // prints False
Console.WriteLine(1 <= a); // prints False
Console.WriteLine(Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(1, a)); // prints 1
```

Why are the comparison operators behaving differently from the default comparer for nullables?

More weirdness:

```
var myList = new List<int?> { 1, 2, 3, default(int?), -1 };
Console.WriteLine(myList.Min()); // prints -1 (consistent with the operators)
Console.WriteLine(myList.OrderBy(i => i).First()); // prints null (nothing) (consistent with the comparator)

Console.WriteLine(new int?[0].Min()); // prints null (nothing)
Console.WriteLine(new int[0].Min()); // throws exception (sequence contains no elements)
```

Comment: There's a problem in your question. Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(1, a) can't return True because it's Integer

Comment: @AndréPena: good call. I've fixed the comment

Comment: Great question. I've been meaning to blog this one for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<=` and `>` are lifted operators which return `false` if either value is `null`.

> For the relational operators
>
> `<`  `>`  `<=`  `>=`
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator produces the value false if one or both operands are null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

Since comparers are used for sorting they need a total ordering where `null` by definition compares as less than every other value. This need takes precedence over consistency with comparison operators. Returning 0 when comparing `null` with any other value isn't possible this that would violate transitivity, so designers had to choose to either emit an error, or sort always sort `null` as smaller or larger than any other value. In .net 1 they decided that `null` is smaller than everything else was decided in for reference types and naturally that decision carried over to nullable value types in .net 2.

The difference between these is pretty similar to how `NaN` behaves on floating points. For example `NaN` doesn't doesn't even equal itself and all comparison operators return false. But when using a comparer `NaN` is equal to itself and smaller than other value except `null`.

`Enumerable.Min` returns the smallest non-null value, and only returns `null` if the sequence contains no non-null values. With such a function `null` typically stands for an omitted value and you're interested in finding the smallest real value.

Comment: TIL lifted operators.